# Subsetting out Columns with NA values

Tags: r, algorithm, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe similar to this (not exactly this) that I'm trying to subset... i want to remove the first two columns, the last two columns, and all columns with NA values...

```
df <- read.table(text="
          a     b    c    d      e      f       g      h
          1     5    6    NA     4      NA      7     9
          3     2    8    NA     9      NA      4     3
          6     5    2    NA     6      NA      1     1
     ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

So far I only got this far:

```
df[, (3:(ncol(df)-2))]
```

which only removes the first two and the last two... but I cant figure out how to remove columns with NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `colSums` and sequence to create a logical vector to subset the columns

```
i1 <- seq_along(df)
df[(!i1 %in% c(1:2, tail(i1,2))) & !colSums(is.na(df))]
#  c e
#1 6 4
#2 8 9
#3 2 6
```

Comment: What if the dataframe is made up of strings?? we cannot use `colSums` you know

Comment: @Onyambu  If you check the code, the `colSums` is done on the logical matrix `is.na(df)` which is based on the NA values. Even if you have character/factor columns, as long as the NAs are NA, then it should work.

Comment: I see what you mean..Thank you.