# Columns With NA Values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in which I want to identify columns that have NA values.

Only about 10% of the columns have NA values, so I only want to list out the columns where the number of NAs is greater than 0.

The line below will bring back all columns, is there a way I can filter out the columns that dont have NA values?

```
colSums(is.na(df))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subsetting out Columns with NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580964/subsetting-out-columns-with-na-values)

Answer (score 0):

To list out columns with at least a single null value you can use:

```
df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist()
```

To list out columns with all null values you can use:

```
df.columns[df.isna().all()].tolist()
```

Comment: Hi There, Thanks for your help. Should the above code work on R? Seems to be python only?